# DataTables API row().data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hi everybody and happy new year :)
So, I use dataTables library. In their web site i found this example, where function must return the row of table, which was clicked.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
} );
```

I try use this example for my code, but i have the error

> Uncaught TypeError: aucTable.row is not a function

my code:

```
var mainTable = $('#mainTable');
$(document).ready(function () {
        mainTable.dataTable({
            'searching': false,
            'ajax': 'assets/static_data/data.json',
            'columns': [
                {
                    title: "Name",
                    data: "name"
                },
                {
                    title: "Office",
                    data: "office"
                },
                {
                    title: "Extn.",
                    data: "extn"
                },
                {
                    title: "Salary",
                    data: "salary"
                },
                {
                    title: "Start date",
                    data: "start_date"
                },
                {
                    title: "Details",
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: "<button class='details-btn btn'>More details</button>",
                    sorting: false
                }
            ]
        });
    });

$('#mainTable').on('click', '.details-btn', function () {

        var selectedRow = aucTable.row(this).data();
        console.log(selectedRow);

        $("<div id='details-dialog'/>").dialog({
            modal: true,
            show: true,
            maxWidth: 620,
            maxHeight: 300,
            minWidth: 500,
            minHeight: 200,
            title: "Hello World"
        });
    });
```

Can somebody tell me, why I have this error? And why i can't get the row, which was clicked?

Tanks for everybody.
Best regard and have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `datatables`, however you might try changing it to the following:

```
var mainTable = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    mainTable = $('#mainTable').dataTable({...});
});

$('#mainTable').on('click', '.details-btn', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var selectedRow = mainTable.row(tr).data();
    console.log(selectedRow);
    //...
});
```

Note that I'm storing the result to the `$('#mainTable').dataTable()` call in the `mainTable` variable so that you can reference it later when calling the `row()` function.

The other thing to note is that in your click handler, it looks like you need to find the `tr` from the datatable - calling `mainTable.row(this)` does not yield a row because `this` is the button that was clicked, not the row of the table.

See [this link](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/29040/get-data-for-selected-row-for-tabletool-button) for an example that seems similar to what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try it too, but selectedRow is undefined... now I have the other problem. Will try to resolve it. Maybe you know how I can resolve it?

Comment: I've updated my answer based your your comment.  Take another look and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the current code, the `acuTable` var not exist. So you can change your code in order to have an acuTable var pointing to the datatable instance, something like:

```
var mainTable = $('#mainTable');
var acuTable;
$(document).ready(function () {
        acuTable = mainTable.dataTable({
            'searching': false,
            'ajax': 'assets/static_data/data.json',
            'columns': [
                {
                    title: "Name",
                    data: "name"
                },
                {
                    title: "Office",
                    data: "office"
                },
                {
                    title: "Extn.",
                    data: "extn"
                },
                {
                    title: "Salary",
                    data: "salary"
                },
                {
                    title: "Start date",
                    data: "start_date"
                },
                {
                    title: "Details",
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: "<button class='details-btn btn'>More details</button>",
                    sorting: false
                }
            ]
        });
    });

$('#mainTable').on('click', '.details-btn', function () {

        var selectedRow = aucTable.row(this).data();
        console.log(selectedRow);

        $("<div id='details-dialog'/>").dialog({
            modal: true,
            show: true,
            maxWidth: 620,
            maxHeight: 300,
            minWidth: 500,
            minHeight: 200,
            title: "Hello World"
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I try it, but selectedRow is undefined... now I have the other problem.
Will try to resolve it